# Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 17 Hangs on Shutdown

Tags: 22.04, shutdown, ufw, xps

When I try to shut down my computer, it hangs on the Ubuntu/Dell splash page. I've used F1 to view the logs, and the last lines are usually the following:

```
systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Powering off.
kvm: exiting hardware virtualization
```

and then every few seconds I get a new UFW BLOCK log, like the following:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=enxc025a57a0fd0 OUT= MAC=(some address) SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=18930 DF PROTO=2
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation about how to read these logs though, so I have no idea how to track down that string in the IN field.

Once every 10 - 15 shutdowns, though, it won't hang on the kvm log, and go further. I was able to catch that once, and the final lines it caught on there were:

```
thunderbolt 1-1: new device found, vendor=0xd4 device=0xb70
thunderbolt 1-1: Dell WD19TB Thunderbolt Dock
usb usb2-port3: attempt power cycle
usb usb2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

And while it hung on that line, it didn't produce UFW Block logs.

I have about 10 more lines for each log, but since I've had to transcribe the logs manually from a photo I took with my phone, I didn't want to flood the post unless they were necessary.

Has anyone seen something like this? I can't find much. I tried blacklisting the kvm scripts, but that didn't get rid of the kvm line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running this command the problem was resolved:

```
shutdown -H -P +0
```

Previously, I had installed the NVIDIA driver using this tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver.

One of the two solved the problem.

Comment: I only installed the NVIDIA driver and was able to shutdown normally. Thank you very much!